# Can not use a singleton class to return its properties

Tags: swift

Hello Guys I have the following code

```
class DeviceListViewController {
    private var currentPeripheral:BLEPeripheral?

    public class var sharedInstance: DeviceListViewController {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = DeviceListViewController()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    func getCurrentPeripheral() -> BLEPeripheral? {
        return currentPeripheral
    }

}
```

But when I use this in another class like following

```
DeviceListViewController.getCurrentPeripheral()
```

it gives me an error telling me the following
Use of instance member "getCurrentPeripheral" on type "DeviceListViewController"; did you mean to use a value of type "DeviceListViewController" instead?

I have no clue what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

p.s. the autocomplete function of xcode passes the ViewController as parameter along with it somehow

```
DeviceListViewController.getCurrentPeripheral(DeviceListViewController)
```

But it results in the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the method on the shared instance, not on the class

```
DeviceListViewController.sharedInstance.getCurrentPeripheral()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But do I need to use the shared instance always? Like when I connect the device in the Devicelistviewcontroller should I do DeviceListViewController.SharedInstance.connectPeripheral instead of connectPeripheral?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *connect the device in the Devicelistviewcontroller*? If the controller is part of the UI view hierarchy you don't need the shared instance at all.

Comment: Well lets say I have another method inside of DeviceListViewController internally that does something. Does it call its own properties via the shared instance or like the usual way? Because if I use the shared instance to get the currentPeripheral it returns nil even though I know there is something connected.

Comment: You don't need to call the shared instance when calling a method from inside the class. But consider that the shared instance might be different from an instance designed in Interface Builder.

Comment: What I needed to do is: DeviceListViewController.sharedInstance.currentPeripheral = BLEPeripheral(peripheral: peripheral, delegate: self) instead of just assigning it to currentPeripheral :) thanks for the help I marked your answer as correct

Comment: With the given code you cannot write into the property `currentPeripheral` from outside directly since the property is private.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using `MyClass.sharedInstance.method()`, you can use this method:

```
class DeviceListViewController {
    private var currentPeripheral:BLEPeripheral?

    public class var sharedInstance: DeviceListViewController {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = DeviceListViewController()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    class func getCurrentPeripheral() -> BLEPeripheral? {
        return DeviceListViewController.sharedInstance.currentPeripheral
    }

}
```

Now you are able to use `MyClass.method()`.